# react native :undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new with react-native and i'm trying to use StackNavigator but it's not working
I'm trying to call a component and render it when you click on a button.
But i'm getting this error : 
`undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')`

This is my main Component:

```
export default class Home extends Component<{}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.email = null;
        this.amount = null;
        this.device = null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.styleSV}>
                <Text
                    style={styles.styleLogin}>
                    Login
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.styleForm}/>
                <TextInput placeholder='email' onChangeText={(text) => this.email }/>
                <TextInput placeholder='amount' onChangeText={(text) => this.amount }/>
                <TextInput placeholder='device' onChangeText={(text) => this.device }/>
                <View style={styles.styleButtonSignup}/>
                <Button
                    onPress={() =>
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('PaypalPayment', { email: this.email })
                    }
                    title='Next'
                />
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}

const NavigationScreen = StackNavigator({
    PaypalPayment: { screen: PaypalPayment },
    Home: { screen: Home}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('paypal', () => NavigationScreen);
```

Comment: Check package.json & give me the version of react-navigation, I will help you after that.

Comment: "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.13"

Comment: Are you sure you didn't render `PaypalPayment ` or `Home` in other place ?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, PaypalPayment render a webview and when my Application start i'm on Home screen

Comment: Weird , I just solved an issue of someone yesterday had the same version.. The mistake  that he did is not here.  . Then , I might need to see your project. BTW, why didn't use Expo stack ( scaffold with create-react-native-app command) ?

Comment: I don’t know what is Expo Stack

Comment: Tested it. No problem here.

Comment: I found out what was my mistake, thanks for the help through :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was my mistake:

On my App.js i didn't call my `StackNavigator`

```
export const RootNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home },
    PaypalPayment: { screen: PaypalPayment }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('paypal', () => RootNavigation);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

   render() {
        return (
            <RootNavigation/>
        )
    }
}
```

Now it's working.

I used this documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/#Introducing-Stack-Navigator

Answer (score 1):

> Tha's how I solved it.

Go to the parent component of the component in which you are using `navigation`.
And call the component as follows.

```
<Component {...this.props} />
```

This makes the `navigation` also available to the child component.